# How to get apps can do the same things?

Tags: android, ios, url-scheme, open-with

Sorry for my poor English. I have a problem & search for this several days :(.
I have to port an app in Android to iOS. It has a function about sharing to other user : users can send a text message to their to present current app, like : "Good app, visit ... to download".

In Android, this function allow user choose one app from all apps in device can send text message (Message, Viber, Skype, ....). It shows a popup with list of apps.

It's like this image :

[image: https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRnbaXCYqJmHJNY5n_2t4WDYU5GAIov_mntasEyAIRDJcAQQ7J1]

It seem to be default behavior in Android, these lines of code is very simple. But in my iOS, i can't find the same way to make it ? I need your help ? 
How can i get these app in my app, i have read about "url scheme" - it can help me go to other app from my app. But most important is i don't know what apps can't send text message in device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A quite similar option on iOS that compared to intent is to use

`UIDocumentInteractionController`

See the documentation here:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIDocumentInteractionController_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009304

For social sharing only (Facebook + Twitter) you can use the SocialFramework on iOS6 or above:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html

Comment: This view controller is seem to show option when I want to open a file. In my case, my app has a Button, when i tap it, i want it show list of apps can send message. Hix, my question's seem to not have exactly answer. Perhap iOS doesn't allow behavior like Android. Thank u so much...

Comment: Indeed UIDocumentInteractionController is mainly intended to share documents (Photo, PDF or text File). The SocialFramework should be used to only share text. Mail can be easily added using MFMailComposeViewController

Comment: Okay, i'll use your solution :D

Answer (score 0):

The functionality that you're describing in Android is the [ACTION_SEND](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_SEND) `Intent`. You can read more about using this Intent to send text content to other apps in the Android Developer Training guide entitled [Sending Simple Data to Other Apps](http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/send.html).

As you seem to want this functionality for users to share the app with other users, iOS has the [Social Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Social/Reference/Social_Framework/_index.html) for Social Sharing, or you could use a custom [UIActionSheet](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIActionSheet_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to present the user with your own list of options.

Comment: Thank 4 ur help. I'll try !